# How can I format a drive using the GPT format on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, gpt

How can I format a drive using the GPT format on OS X? I don't see this option in Disk Tools.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you mean Disk Utility, you have to select the drive itself (as opposed to an individual partition)*, and then you will see a Partition tab. Then on that tab, select the partition layout you want, and at the bottom click 'Options...' — you'll be able to select GUID Partition Table from there.

( * Apologies if this is patronising, but just to be 100% clear, in order to change the partition scheme you'll have to erase the entire drive. You can't change it for just one partition. )

Comment: But is one of the available formats GPT?

Comment: GPT stands for GUID Partition Table (unless you've hit on something i'm not familiar with, but i even googled it), so yes. In the partition options pane there are three partition schemes, and GPT is one of them.

Comment: What do I do if the partition button is grayed out?

Answer (score 2):

Not enough rep to comment but for everyone struggling, if your partition button is greyed out, click view at the top and make sure it's set to "Show All Devices" and select the drive itself, not the partition which you've probably been selecting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is clear enough to suffice as an answer, and resolved my issue.